# WPF 3d -- understanding texture coordinates

Tags: wpf, 3d, textures

In my attempt to understand texture coordinates in WPF 3D, I started off with a very simple example: a single triangle, a linear-gradient brush, and texture coordinates, as follows:

```
        <Viewport3D>
        <ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                <Model3DGroup>
                    <GeometryModel3D>

                        <!-- Geometry -->
                        <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                            <MeshGeometry3D 
                            Positions="10 10 0, 
                                       20 10 0, 
                                       15 15 0"
                            TriangleIndices="0 1 2"
                            TextureCoordinates="0.5 0.0,
                                                0.5 0.0,
                                                0.5 0.0" />
                        </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>

                        <!-- Foreground and background brushes -->
                        <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                            <DiffuseMaterial>
                                <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5 0" EndPoint="0.5 1">
                                        <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                            <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.0"/>
                                            <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.50"/>
                                            <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="1.0"/>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                            </DiffuseMaterial>
                        </GeometryModel3D.Material>

                        <GeometryModel3D.BackMaterial>
                            <DiffuseMaterial Brush="Blue" />
                        </GeometryModel3D.BackMaterial>
                    </GeometryModel3D>

                    <!-- Lighting -->
                    <AmbientLight Color="White" />

                </Model3DGroup>
            </ModelVisual3D.Content>
        </ModelVisual3D>

        <!-- Camera -->
        <Viewport3D.Camera>
            <PerspectiveCamera Position="15 12 10"
                           LookDirection="0 0 -1"
                           UpDirection="0 1 0"
                           FieldOfView="90">
            </PerspectiveCamera>
        </Viewport3D.Camera>
    </Viewport3D>
```

What I'm expecting is a **Red** triangle, since all y-coordinates of the textures are 0.0, but what I get is a **Green** one! Can someone please explain this behavior, so that I can correct my understanding, and move on to larger models? Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Usually, texture coordinates are defined in the range [0, 1]. However, WPF allows you to use any multiple. But let's stay with the [0, 1] range for the beginning. Then the gradient you defined looks like this:

[image: Gradient]

If we change the texture coordinates to the following:

```
TextureCoordinates="0.5 0.0,
                    0.5 0.0,
                    0.5 1.0"
```

then we get a nice gradient on the triangle:

[image: Triangle]

The texture coordinates are interpolated in the triangle and the appropriate colors are fetched from the gradient. The bottom left vertex has texture coordinate (0.5, 0), which is red in the gradient. The top vertex has texture coordinate (0.5, 1), which is green in the gradient.

As I said, texture coordinates can be used relatively. They are scaled by their bounding box. So we could also define the following coordinates to get the same result (scaled by 2 and shifted by (0.5, 0.5)):

```
TextureCoordinates="1.5 0.5,
                    1.5 0.5,
                    1.5 2.5"
```

And this is exactly the point, why you get a green triangle with your texture coordinates. Because all coordinates are the same, the bounding box is 0 units wide and 0 units high. There is just no reasonable way to fit an arbitrary texture coordinate into this degenerate bounding box. I can't tell why WPF chooses the green edge. Probably undefined behavior.

Concluding, always define proper texture coordinates that do not result in a degenerate bounding box.

You may have noticed that the alternative texture coordinates produce a bounding box with zero width. However, this is ok in this case, because the gradient does not change along the u-direction.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very detailed answer. However, if I use the following texture coordinates with the same points: TextureCoordinates="0.5 0.75, 0.5 0.75, 0.5 1.0" I expect a somewhat yellowish green triangle since the texture y-coordinates are all greater than 0.5 (where the red ends and yellow begins), but  what I see is one with definite red tones at the bottom. I'm still not getting the entire hang of it...Thx!

Comment: That's because the coordinates are fit into the [0, 1] range. So the resulting v-coordinates are 0, 0, 1. You could change the gradient to achieve the desired effect (`StartPoint="0.5 -3"`)

Comment: Thanks, again. Can you please elaborate your answer. I tried the start point "0.5 -3", like you suggested and like magic I saw the change! But I'm still not very clear about it. Specifically, how do the resulting v-coordinates come out be "0,0,1" when the start point was "0.5 0.0"? I'm not sure what you mean by "fit into the range [0, 1]". Thank you so much to get me this far...I think I'm almost there!

Comment: I think I get it now. The bounding box (actually the range, since it's linear here) of the v-coordinates (which is 0.25) is matched with the brush's y-range, so if I spread the brush range to make it 4 * (0.25), ending at 1, it works. Crude explanation...but perhaps right?

Comment: Keeping the original brush start point at (0.5 0), the same effect (yellowish-green) will be seen if I add a dummy position (say [0 0 0]) with texture coordinate (0.5 0). This will extend the v-range to [0 1]. And that was perhaps what you meant, correct? The caffeine took its time kicking in! :)

Comment: Yeah, I think you got it :)

Answer (score 1):

See
[Daniel Lehenbauer's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/danlehen/archive/2005/11/06/489627.aspx)
for a helpful description of the 2D to 3D mapping procedure in WPF.